# Two methods for the Nash equilibrium give different answers; which is correct?

Tags: conditional-probability, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Suppose we have a game, played in which Alice and Bob play mixed strategies:
(Sorry about the spacing, but I don't know how to put a table or tab spacing in this text box.)

Alice plays Dove with probability p and Hawk with probability (1-p)

Bob plays Dove with probability q and Hawk with probability (1-q)

Payoffs are, with Alice being the first coordinate, and Bob the second:

Dove, Dove: (2,3)

Dove, Hawk: (3,4)

Hawk, Dove (5,6)

Hawk, Hawk (7,8)

To figure out p and q for a Nash equilibrium, which one of the following reasoning procedures is correct:

First method:

Alice's payoff, if she plays Dove, is 2q + 4(1-q) = A

Alice's payoff, if she plays Hawk, is 6q + 8(1-q)= B

Bob's payoff, if he plays Dove, is 3p + 5(1-p) = C

Bob's payoff, if he plays Hawk, is 7p + 9(1-p)= D

For a Nash equilibrium, A=B & C=D, so we solve.....

Second method:

The probabilities of each move are

Dove, Dove: p*q

Dove, Hawk: p*(1-q)

Hawk, Dove: (1-p)*q

Hawk, Hawk (1-p)*(1-q)

so that
Alice's payoff, if she plays Dove, is 2pq + 4p(1-q) = A

Alice's payoff, if she plays Hawk, is 6(1-p)q + 8(1-p)(1-q)= B

Bob's payoff, if he plays Dove, is 3pq + 5(1-p)q = C

Bob's payoff, if he plays Hawk, is 7p(1-q) + 9(1-p)(1-q)= D

For a Nash equilibrium, A=B & C=D, so we solve.....

Which method (or neither) is correct? Thanks for any indications.

Answer (score 0):

Both players are trying to maximize their payoffs.  In this game, switching from Dove to Hawk always increases your payoff.  So the only Nash equilibrium is 
(Hawk,Hawk).

In order to have a $2 \times 2$ game with a mixed strategy equilibrium, Bob must be able to make Alice's expected payoffs equal, and Alice must be able to make Bob's expected payoffs equal.  This leads to the first method (but the resulting $p$ and $q$ must be probabilities, therefore in the interval $[0,1]$).

The second method is just completely wrong.  $2pq + 4p(1-q)$ is not ``Alice's payoff if she plays Dove'''.

Comment: I knew that the second method was wrong, so my real question is: why is the second method wrong? (The particular numbers chosen in the example are irrelevant, although then why does reasoning give the solution but the equations have no solution?) That is, Prob(Alice plays Dove) = Prob((Dove, Dove) OR (Dove, Hawk)) = Prob(Dove,Dove)+P(Dove,Hawk) = pq + p(1-q), so in the pq portion that (Dove, Dove) occurs, she receives 2, so she gets 2pq; in the p(1-q) portion that (Dove, Hawk) occurs, she will receive 4, so she receives 4p(1-q), and so her total is the sum. Wrong, but why?

Comment: Because in deciding what to do (knowing Bob's strategy), Alice should compare her payoff *if* she plays Dove to her payoff *if* she pays Hawk.  Method 2 is weighting those payoffs by the probabilities she plays them in her current strategy.